# Calendar API unable to create a meet link , python

Tags: python, json, api, google-calendar-api

I'm trying to create a event in google calendar using calendar API , event is created successfully but im not getting the meet link.

**Parameter**

```
event={
      "calendarId": "primary",
      "conferenceDataVersion": 1,
      "end": {
        'dateTime': '2020-12-28T17:00:00-07:00',
        'timeZone': 'Asia/Kolkata'
      },
      "start": {
        'dateTime': '2020-12-28T09:00:00-07:00',
        'timeZone': 'Asia/Kolkata'
      },
      "conferenceData": {
        "createRequest": {
          "conferenceSolutionKey": {
            "type": "hangoutsMeet"
          },
          "requestId": "RandomString"
        }
      },
      "summary": "titles are cool"
      }
```

> **Response**

```
{
   "kind":"calendar#event",
   "etag":"REMOVED_BY_ME",
   "id":"REMOVED_BY_ME",
   "status":"confirmed",
   "htmlLink":"https://www.google.com/calendar/event?eid=REMOVED_BY_ME",
   "created":"2020-11-19T15:30:13.000Z",
   "updated":"2020-11-19T15:30:13.738Z",
   "summary":"Inserted via API",
   "creator":{
      "email":"sahiljena46@gmail.com",
      "self":True
   },
   "organizer":{
      "email":"sahiljena46@gmail.com",
      "self":True
   },
   "start":{
      "dateTime":"2020-10-19T20:30:00+05:30"
   },
   "end":{
      "dateTime":"2020-10-19T21:30:00+05:30"
   },
   "iCalUID":"REMOVED_BY_ME@google.com",
   "sequence":0,
   "reminders":{
      "useDefault":True
   }
}
```

PS : Ignore REMOVED_BY_ME text , i replaced it with the original

> **All i want is a meet link!!**

Comment: What does your response object look like?

Comment: @ziganotschka Updated question with response

Answer (score 4):

### You should pass all parameters other than the `calendarId` and `conferenceDataVersion` within the event body

Sample:

```py
body = {
      "calendarId": "primary",
      "conferenceDataVersion": 1,
      "end": {
        'dateTime': '2020-12-28T17:00:00-07:00',
        'timeZone': 'Asia/Kolkata'
      },
      "start": {
        'dateTime': '2020-12-28T09:00:00-07:00',
        'timeZone': 'Asia/Kolkata'
      },
      "conferenceData": {
        "createRequest": {
          "conferenceSolutionKey": {
            "type": "hangoutsMeet"
          },
          "requestId": "RandomString"
        }
      },
      "summary": "titles are cool"
      }
event = service.events().insert(calendarId='primary', conferenceDataVersion=1, body=body).execute()
```