# how to insert property google calendar api hangoutmeeting

Tags: python, google-calendar-api

I try created a calendar using python. And want to create an attached meeting.
I have read through this document [here](https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/v3/reference/events).
And add this into body of events().insert()

```
"conferenceData":{
    "createRequest":{
       "conferenceSolutionKey":{
           "type": 'hangoutsMeet'
                      }
                   }  },
```

but it only generates calendar like this
[image]

Comment: I think that this answer is for your answer. https://stackoverflow.com/a/64915775

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your reply, I understood that your issue was resolved. So, I flagged this as a duplicated question.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Calendar API unable to create a meet link , python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64880914/calendar-api-unable-to-create-a-meet-link-python)